# How to edit the date column in excel using macros to get it to the common format "dd/mm/yyyy"

Tags: vba, excel, date, macros

The question is related to date & time. I was trying to create a macro in excel for editing the date column to change all the dates previously entered to  the common format "dd/mm/yyyy". But when the date is separated using "." or "-" it is not being identified as a date. Tried replacing the separators to "/",and then the date was considered from right to left.
The macro I tried is as given below:

```
Sub Date_Edit() 

Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Sheets(1).Range("B1:B1000").Replace ".", "/"

For i = 2 To 1000                                        
    d = Cells(i, 2).Value
    a = CDate(d)
    Cells(i, 3) = FormatDateTime(d, 2)
Next i

Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"  

End Sub
```

Comment: It's recommended to not use `Select` as it slows down subroutines. Instead of using `Columns("C:C").Select` and `Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"` you can just use: `Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"` similarly you can just use `Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight` in the first line of your code.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is here:

```
d = Cells(i, 2).Value ' here you set d as the variable
a = CDate(d)  ' at this point a is the current variable
Cells(i, 3) = FormatDateTime(d, 2) ' and here you use d again.
```

I think you need to replace the `d` with `a` in the FormatDateTime.

The CDate() converts a value to a date.
The FormateDateTime() needs a date-value to function. `d` is not a date-value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the standard format is `"mm/dd/yyyy"` not  `"dd/mm/yyyy"`.  When you try and convert `"dd/mm/yyyy"` to a standard datevalue you have to swap the days and months.

This function will only handle date values.

```
Function FixDDMMYYYY(DateString As String) As Date
    Dim arDateParts() As String

    If InStr(DateString, ".") Then
        arDateParts = Split(DateString, ".")
    ElseIf InStr(DateString, "-") Then
        arDateParts = Split(DateString, "-")
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        FixDDMMYYYY = DateSerial(arDateParts(2), arDateParts(1), arDateParts(0))
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```